# How to convert List<Entity> to a string?

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist

Here is the code :
I have a entity named ClassA which consists of following attribute

```
  @JsonProperty("rowDeleted")
    private Boolean rowDeleted;
    @JsonProperty("start")
    private List<Start> start = null;
    @JsonProperty("end")
    private List<End> end = null;
    @JsonProperty("rows")
    private List<Row> rows = null;
```

And Row is another entity which consists of attributes:

```
 @JsonProperty("cells")
    private List<Cell> cells = null;
    @JsonProperty("clusteringKey")
    private String clusteringKey;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

And Cell is another entity:

```
 @JsonProperty("deleted")
    private Boolean deleted;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I am getting an object of ClassA and want to convert it into another entity which is ClassB contains fields:

```
private String end;
    private String key;
    private String keyspacename;
    private String partitiondeleted;
    private String rowdeleted;
    private String rows;
    private String start;
    private String tablename;
    private String triggerdate;
    private String triggertime;
```

So basically i want to convert List rows of ClassA to String rows of ClassB.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted a string which could represent json format so modified my toString() as per my requirement and it solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a list of class A.

```
 List<A> list= . . . ;
 List<B> newList=list
  .stream()
  .map(obj-> new B()
     .setKey(obj.getKey())
     .setKeyspacename(//set which field of class A will be saved)
     .setPartitiondeleted()
     // set more fields
    )
  .collect(Collecters.toList());
```

and then serialize this `newlist` into String by using jakson.